# How to sort categories by number of posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this syntax for ordering categories by the number of posts in each categories.

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&show_count=1&child_of=3&number=5&orderby=count'); ?>
```

Still it's not working.. It shows the categories ordered alphabetically. Please help me!

Please see the sidebar

http://www.primobazaar.com/

Comment: Please provide the code you are currently using.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to specify the code...

<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&show_count=1&child_of=3&number=5&orderby=count'); ?>

Comment: @user3280106, please edit the question and put the code directly in it. It is much easier to read there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code I have modified from another answer

```
<?php
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach (get_categories('orderby=count&order=ASC') as $category ) 
    {
         if( $category->category_parent == '0') 
         { 
            $url = '';
            $url =  site_url() . '/' . $category->taxonomy . '/' . $category->slug ;
            echo '<li class="cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id . '"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $category->name . ' (' . $category->count . ')</a></li>';

         }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Here is the question that led to the answer.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-get-wp_list_categories-to-list-by-count-help

Removing the `$category->category_parent == '0'` if check, will mean that all categories will be selected and not just parents.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Change the line `('orderby=count&order=ASC')` to `('orderby=count&order=DESC')` for descending ordering. Also you will have to add your further arguments etc, ie `&child_of=3&number=5`.

Answer (score 0):

### [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
    <?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',   <----------------
    'order'            => 'DESC',        <----------------
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
 ?>
```

You can sort them how you want like `menu_order,post_date` etc.

Comment: Presumably this is simply getting posts and ordering them by a field, rather than ordering an array of posts by categories depending on the post count.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like sort them by the number of posts in each category. Categories with maximum number posts should be at the top, nor alphabetically neither by date. How to solve it?